# How to split and numbering of 2 columns into 4 columns by 50rows each?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a list of entries (A2 to A2000 in numbers, B2 to B2000) with headers (A1 and B1). On the same sheet, how do I split them into columns and numbering them in sets of 50 each?

For example,

```
Number    Title
1         A
2         B
3         C
4         D
5         E
6         F
7         G
8         H
9         I
10        J
11        K
12        L
13        M
14        N
15        O
```

How do I change to this format as below?

```
    Number    Title    Number    Title
    1         A        6         F
    2         B        7         G
    3         C        8         H
    4         D        9         I
    5         E        10        J
    11        K        16        P
    12        L        17        Q
    13        M        18        R
    14        N        19        S
    15        O        20        T

and so on all the way to 2000
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Hi. im not familiar with the version. however when i clicked on account and under about, it states Microsoft Excel for microsoft 365.

Comment: If your data including headers is `A1:B2000` then try in `D1`: `=IF(ROW()=1,INDEX($A$1:$B$1,MOD(COLUMN(),2)+1),INDEX($A:$B,FLOOR.MATH(ROW()-2,5)+ROW()+CHOOSE(COLUMN()-3,0,0,5,5),MOD(COLUMN(),2)+1))`. Drag right to `G1` and down as far as needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Shown method is not smart enough but it's working.**

[image]

- Formula in cell `C1`:

  ```
  =IF(ROW($A1)>10,"",INDEX($A:$A,ROWS($A$1:A1)+(COLUMNS($A$1:A1)-1)*10))
  ```
- *Fill the formula across columns.*
- `*10` is editable, you may adjust it on Rows to split.
- Now insert blank column between column C & D

[image]

- Formula in cell `D1`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B20,   MATCH(C1,A1:A20,0)),"")
  ```
- Formula in cell `F1`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B20,MATCH(E1,A1:A20,0)),"")
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Hi. Nice!. Thanks alot for the help! Appreciate!

Comment: Hi @MCMC ,,, glad to help U,,, now if you feel,, you may [accept its as answer](https://superuser.com/tour) as well up vote also ,, keep asking ☺

Comment: Hi @MCMC , if u are comfortable with Macro then I can suggest you , will automate everything just by a click!